# Three.js how to make 2d text sprite rotate with object

Tags: three.js

I am using three.js in a project and I have made a cube with MultiMaterials, made of six MeshPhongMaterials loaded from png files.

I need to add 2d text to each face of the cube and make it accompany the cube´s rotation whenever I rotate it to a certain degree.

I was able to add a 2d transparent text sprite from a canvas onto my scene. But to be honest I have no clue how to make it follow the cube´s rotation. (not the camera rotation, the camera is still).

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Add the text object as a child of the cube. `cube.add( textMesh )`.

Comment: That did the trick @WestLangley, thank you so much! Please post as answer so that I can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scene graph is hierarchical in three.js, and an object's transform is relative to its parent's transform. Therefore you can use this pattern:

```
scene.add( mesh );
mesh.add( text_sprite );
```

three.js r.80